# Getting angle between all points in array

Tags: python, performance, array, numpy

I have got some code that calculates the angle between all of the points in an array. It works, but it is quite slow. This is because it has complexity O(n^2). It has to loop through the array and apply the `angle` function to every combination of points.

```
import math
import random
def angle(pos1,pos2):
    dx=pos2[0]-pos1[0]
    dy=pos2[1]-pos1[1]
    rads=math.atan2(dy,dx)
    rads%=2*math.pi
    degs=math.degrees(rads)
    return degs
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos=[random.randint(0,500) for _ in range(2)]#random x,y
        self.angles=[]
points=[Point() for _ in range(100)]
for point in points:
    point.angles=[] #so that each frame, they will be recalculated
    for otherC in points:
        if otherC is point:continue #don't check own angle
        ang=angle(point.pos,otherC.pos)
        point.angles.append(ang)
```

I feel like it could be greatly sped up by using numPy or some other method. I did some searching ([here](https://www.google.com/search?q=numpy%20angle%20between%20points%20in%20array)), but all I could find was functions to get angle between planes, or complex numbers. I just need simple arrays. **How can this code be optimized for more speed?**

Comment: [`itertools.combinations`](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/itertools#itertools.combinations)

Comment: How are you using this,  do you need all the angles?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, I need all the angles. Each point is a creature, and I need to see what other creatures are in its field of view.

Comment: @pydude That sounds to me like you don't need all the points. You just need specific ones in specific directions. And since we don't know which direction the monsters are pointing, we can't help simplify that.

Comment: @Peilonrayz But specific direction==angle (I think),  so I need to see if the points are in that specific direction.

Comment: @pydude If a monster is standing at `(0, 0)` and looking in the positive `x` direction, with a FOV of 180, then you don't need to use `tan`. You just need to check that the point has a positive or 0 x position. If you're using an efficient space tree, then you don't have to visit any of the points to get the result.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I can see how that would work for monsters at 90-interval headings, but what about one at 32.7 degree heading? Perhaps you should write up an answer, because I don't know what an "efficient space tree" is.

Comment: @pydude I won't write an answer to a hypothetical question. If you'd like my input, then ask a question with all the code.

Comment: @Peilonrayz more specific version [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200123/checking-where-if-another-creature-lies-in-a-creatures-field-of-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically, if you have the angle between \$ A(x_1, y_1) \$ and \$ B(x_2, y_2) \$, given as:

$$ \theta = \tan^{-1}{\dfrac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}} \tag{in degrees} $$

then, the angle between \$ B \$ and \$ A \$ would be:

$$ \phi = 180° + \theta \mod {360°} $$

The \$ \mod{360} \$ is simply there if you want results in the interval \$ [0, 360) \$.

---

With the above, you'll only need to calculate angles between 2 points once, halving the number of calculations performed.